# how to stay image constant on hover

Tags: html

Here is the code which i am using on my page

### HTML

```
 <a href="#" class="bac" data-role="none" style="color:#fff;">
  <strong>An&uacute;nciese gratis</strong>
 </a>
```

### CSS

```
.bac{

background:url("http://wstation.inmomundo.com/static02/costarica/sprites_botones1.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
display: block;
font:15px/18px Arial;
height: 22px;
padding: 6px 18px 4px 4px;
text-decoration: none;
margin-right:-4px;

}


.bac:hover{
background-attachment:scroll;
background-position:0px -35px;
background-image:url("http://wstation.inmomundo.com/static02/costarica/sprites_botones1.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:22px;
padding:6px 18px 4px 4px;

}
```

Here is the demo  http://jsfiddle.net/Lc4Ky/1/ (open in google chrome browser)
When i open this in google chrome, on hover the image is going off for a second then its showing hover effect.The image is going off only first time on each refresh.
But i want this should be stable.Is there any solution for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: Hover State images cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333695/css-hover-state-images-cache)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, but i think you should not apply

```
background-image:url("http://wstation.inmomundo.com/static02/costarica/sprites_botones1.png");
```

again on hover, so your hover class should be

```
 .bac:hover{
background-position:0px -35px; 
}
```

**Edit:** Also it is going off because you apply `background-image` again in hover and google take is as brand new image and take some time to load first time, but after that google pick it from cache and it never goes off again until you reload the page, if your image is in same domain then don't give the full url of image `http://wstation.inmomundo.com/static02/costarica/sprites_botones1.png`, give the relative path of image like images/sprites_botones1.png

Comment: How does this differ from what oezi said?

Comment: I started it before seeing answer of oezi, he is just litle fast

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to redefine everything in the `:hover`-block. just change the `background-position`:

```
.bac:hover{
    background-position:0px -35px;  
}
```

[see it working on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lc4Ky/2/)